# Why are there inconsistencies in Bing Maps RouteResult?

Tags: bing-maps

I am using the Bing Maps AJAX Control 7.0.

I am clicking on the map, getting the locations of the mouse clicks, creating waypoints from the clicks and calculating a driving route with `DirectionsManager.calculateDirections()`

Then when the directions have been returned I call `DirectionsManager.getRouteResult()` to get a reference to the calculated `Route` object. At this point my code hits a break point so I can examine the `Route`.

What I have noticed is that invariably there are inconsistencies.

- The last latitude and longitude of one `subLeg.routePath` often don't match the first latitude and longitude of the next `subLeg.routePath`. Normally they differ by 0.000001 so I presume it is a rounding inconsistency.
- The `routeLeg.startWaypointLocation` does not match the latitude and longitude of the start of the first subLeg's `routePath` nor does `routeLeg.endWaypointLocation` match the end of the last subLeg's `routePath`.
- I might not expect the `startWaypointLocation` and `endWaypointLocation` to match the lats and longs in the `routePath` but I certainly would expect the `subLeg.actualStart` and `subLeg.actualEnd` to be the same as the start and end of the `routePath`. They aren't, they are frequently not the same.
- Finally within the `routePath`, `actualStart` and `actualEnd` there is inconsistency in the precision of lats and longs. Sometimes they are to 6 decimal places and sometimes they are to the full precision of the float number.

It seems that every time i calculate some directions there are most or all of these inconsistencies in the result.

Has anybody else noticed this? Why are there these inconsistencies? Is there anything that can be done about it?

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you add your waypoints by location and bing adjust lat lon of them to the most near point on street or road (reverse geocoding) So it can name your start and end points.
Maybe i'm wrongbut it seems something like that.